# Gradle Kotlin DSL: Configure task: unresolved reference

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've tried with:

```
tasks.withType<com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask> {
    reports.xml.enabled = false
    reports.html.enabled = true
}
```

I got these compilation errors:

```
Script compilation errors:

  Line 20:     reports.xml.enabled = false
                           ^ Unresolved reference: enabled

  Line 21:     reports.html.enabled = true
                            ^ Unresolved reference: enabled
```

My script is:

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.spotbugs") version "1.6.9"
}

tasks.withType<com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask> {
    reports.xml.enabled = false
    reports.html.enabled = true
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

I've also tried with

```
tasks.withType<com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask> {
    reports { xml { enabled = false } }
    reports { html { enabled = true } }
}
```

Then I'm getting:

```
Script compilation errors:

  Line 30:         html {
                   ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
                       public inline operator fun <T : Any, C : NamedDomainObjectContainer<TypeVariable(T)>> TypeVariable(C).invoke(configuration: NamedDomainObjectContainerScope<TypeVariable(T)>.() -> Unit): TypeVariable(C) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> Closure<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> Closure<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(x: Any?): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> Closure<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(vararg xs: Any?): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <V> Callable<TypeVariable(V)>.invoke(): TypeVariable(V) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public inline operator fun <reified T> Action<in TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(target: TypeVariable(T)): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> NamedDomainObjectProvider<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(action: TypeVariable(T).() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       @Incubating public operator fun ArtifactHandler.invoke(configuration: ArtifactHandlerScope.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       @Incubating public operator fun DependencyConstraintHandler.invoke(configuration: DependencyConstraintHandlerScope.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public inline operator fun <T> ExtraPropertiesExtension.invoke(initialValueProvider: () -> TypeVariable(T)): InitialValueExtraPropertyDelegateProvider<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> ExtraPropertiesExtension.invoke(initialValue: TypeVariable(T)): InitialValueExtraPropertyDelegateProvider<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> Spec<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(arg: TypeVariable(T)): Boolean defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public inline operator fun TaskContainer.invoke(configuration: TaskContainerScope.() -> Unit): TaskContainer defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

  Line 31:             enabled = true
                       ^ Val cannot be reassigned

  Line 31:             enabled = true
                                 ^ The boolean literal does not conform to the expected type NamedDomainObjectSet<SingleFileReport!>!

  Line 34:             destination = "$path/index.html"
                       ^ Unresolved reference: destination

  Line 36:         xml {
                   ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
                       public inline operator fun <T : Any, C : NamedDomainObjectContainer<TypeVariable(T)>> TypeVariable(C).invoke(configuration: NamedDomainObjectContainerScope<TypeVariable(T)>.() -> Unit): TypeVariable(C) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> Closure<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> Closure<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(x: Any?): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> Closure<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(vararg xs: Any?): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <V> Callable<TypeVariable(V)>.invoke(): TypeVariable(V) defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public inline operator fun <reified T> Action<in TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(target: TypeVariable(T)): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> NamedDomainObjectProvider<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(action: TypeVariable(T).() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       @Incubating public operator fun ArtifactHandler.invoke(configuration: ArtifactHandlerScope.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       @Incubating public operator fun DependencyConstraintHandler.invoke(configuration: DependencyConstraintHandlerScope.() -> Unit): Unit defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public inline operator fun <T> ExtraPropertiesExtension.invoke(initialValueProvider: () -> TypeVariable(T)): InitialValueExtraPropertyDelegateProvider<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> ExtraPropertiesExtension.invoke(initialValue: TypeVariable(T)): InitialValueExtraPropertyDelegateProvider<TypeVariable(T)> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public operator fun <T> Spec<TypeVariable(T)>.invoke(arg: TypeVariable(T)): Boolean defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
                       public inline operator fun TaskContainer.invoke(configuration: TaskContainerScope.() -> Unit): TaskContainer defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

  Line 37:             enabled = false
                                 ^ The boolean literal does not conform to the expected type NamedDomainObjectSet<SingleFileReport!>!

6 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Each report is of type `org.gradle.api.reporting.SingleFileReport` so in Kotlin you want to invoke the `setEnabled()` method with a boolean argument, as in

```
tasks.withType<com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask> {
    reports {
        xml.setEnabled(false)
        html.setEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

or if you want to use Kotlin's syntactic sugar

```
reports {
    xml.isEnabled = false
    html.isEnabled = true
}
```